# Is it possible? Numpy array with default value for invalid indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, windowing

I have a project where I would benefit from a numpy array that would return a default value (e.g. 0) when indexed out of bounds (as determined by its shape.)
Is there any easy way to implement this? Is there any library that will do this for me? This behavior needs to hold for all forms of "fancy indexing" (slices, boolean arrays, lists of tuples, etc.).

My primary purpose for this is for implementing a segmented algorithm. I need to run it in two passes, where in one pass the entire array is shifted or rotated.
This may cause some segments to fall outside the bounds of the array.

I'd prefer if there was a native implementation of this behavior, since nested loops in python would be quite slow.

Comment: you could add a try except block and return a value (e.g -1) when an IndexOutOfBounds error pop up

Comment: @Farid Fakhry I need to catch this error on a per-index basis. All indices inside of the array must return the corresponding value.

Comment: If the distance you can end up outside the bounds isn't arbitrary, then you can just pad with zeros (using `np.pad`).  It's relatively easy to manipulate the indices to match the new, padded shape.